# Create postgres view from table with dynamic casting

Tags: arrays, postgresql, view, type-conversion

I want to create a generic query that will allow me to create a view (from a table) and convert all Array columns into strings.

Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_1 AS
SELECT *
    for each column_name in columns
        CASE WHEN pg_typeof(column_name) == TEXT[] THEN array_to_string(column_name)
        ELSE column_name
FROM table_1;
```

I guess that I can do that with `stored procedure` but I'm looking for solution in pure SQL, if it can be to much complex.

Comment: You cannot do it like this. Either write dynamic SQL in a function or user something like `psql`'s `\gexec` on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query to do such conversion. You can then customize it to create the view and execute it.

```
SELECT
  'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_table_view AS SELECT ' ||  string_agg( 
                CASE 
                    WHEN pg_catalog.format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) LIKE '%[]' THEN 'array_to_string(' || pg_attribute.attname || ', '','') AS ' || pg_attribute.attname
                    ELSE pg_attribute.attname
                END, ', ' ORDER BY attnum ASC)
                || ' FROM ' || min(pg_class.relname) || ';'
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_attribute
INNER JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_class ON pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid
INNER JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
WHERE
    pg_attribute.attnum > 0
    AND NOT pg_attribute.attisdropped
    AND pg_namespace.nspname = 'my_schema'
    AND pg_class.relname = 'my_table'
; \gexec
```

Example:

```
create table tarr (id integer, t_arr1 text[], regtext text, t_arr2 text[], int_arr integer[]);
```

==>

```
 SELECT id, array_to_string(t_arr1) AS t_arr1, regtext, array_to_string(t_arr2) AS t_arr2, int_arr FROM tarr;
```

Comment: not sure I follow how the two queries connect. In your example you created a table and them used "array_to_string" for each array column and I want to do it dynamically with explicit stating each column name